# How to recognize blurry bar code image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning, barcode-scanner

[image]
This is my bar code image. I can not scan the code information use zbar or zxing. Are there any image processing or computer vision method which can make this be recognized?

Comment: With 1069 reputation you should know that asking for external resources, tools and libraries is off-topic...

Comment: Thanks for remind. I have tried to search google and github and also tried lots of opencv method (e.g. binaryzation, history equalization, gamma transformation.).  These did not work, so I turned to SO to get some advicement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try blind  or supervised deblurring methods such as Lucy-Richardson deconvolution. This seems to be an EAN128, and blur information can be extracted from the known bars (EAN signature).

Or try advanced methods such as in https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2898212/ (and cited articles).

But honestly, chances are fairly low.